# Excel: If cell exists in another tab, how to copy entire row

Tags: excel

hoping somebody can help as I'm rather stuck!

I have a Master tab which displays all individual products I sell. Each product has a unique Product Code.

Other tabs contain things like bundles, displaying a small select amount of products which can also be found in the Master tab.

I want a formula, so if I enter a product code in a new tab, it will locate the same product code from the Master tab and copy the entire row to this new tab. Furthermore, if the price in the Master tab changes, I would like it to automatically change the price in the new tab where the same product exists.

On the Master tab, the data ranges from A3:S904 (row 2 has the table headers). The product codes are in Column C; this can be moved if a formula would require so.

Looking forward to suggestion,
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `vlookup` function.  If you do a search in google you'll get lots of tutorials that explain how to use it.  It should do exaclty what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks a lot for your response. I have researched it the best I can, I think my confusion comes in when it involves cross-referencing to other tabs. I just get errors each time!

Comment: If you add your formula to your question then I can try and work out why it's not working. It should look something like this if your code is in A1 `=vlookup($A1,DataSheet!$A$3:$S$904,2,false)`.  Notice that I've used $ to lock the cell that contains the code and lock the range that is being looked at.  This is to prevent these from changing as you autofill accross and down.  I just re-read your question and noticed that you said the Code is in column C.  It will be easier if you move it to column A.

Comment: Apologies if I have been somewhat unclear so far! I've taken screenshots, hopefully this will help. oi63.tinypic.com/e1bwy8.jpg This is a screenshot of the Master tab with all the products on. http://oi68.tinypic.com/1zn3p7t.jpg This is a screenshot of another tab which will be a bundle of three products. If one of the products in the bundle were to be Ball Pool Balls, with product code 100163, I would like to be able to type in "100163" into cell A8 of the tab in the second screenshot, and all the other values in the entire row would autopopulate. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: links above for screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an item to appear on row 5 of the new tab, with the product code in column C:

In D5 of the new tab, enter:

=vlookup($C5, Master!$C:$S, Column()-2, 0)

Copy this formula across the row as far as column S.

Now enter the product code in C5.

If you need an extra row for another product, e.g. in row 6, copy row 5 and paste to row 6, then edit the product code in C6 to the new value.

Since these are formulas, changes to Master will instantly appear in the new tab. The caveat is, if you delete a row (product) from Master then any formula looking at that row will change to #REF!

Explanation: Column() returns the column the formula is in. Since Vlookup works by offset from the reference column and for D5 you want the value from e.g. Column "D" (column 4) of Master, which is column 2 of the lookup range, you subtract 2 from Column().

Do you also want columns A and B from Master?

Comment: Hi Winterknell,

Thanks for your response.

I tried to follow your advice but something isn't pulling through right. I've taken some screenshots which I hope will make things a bit clearer here,

http://oi64.tinypic.com/ri4sk1.jpg

As you can see,this is the Master tab. Let's take the very first product as an example,product ID 100163, whose row I want to cross over to another tab:

http://oi65.tinypic.com/2077z92.jpg

I want a formula where, if I entered 100163 into cell A8 of the tab in that second screenshot, the rest of the row in that tab would autocomplete. Hope this helps

Comment: Read my explanation of what the formula is doing. My example had the product code in column C of the new tab, you say you want it in Column A. OK. If the product code is in column C on Master and you want it in column A on the new tab, you need to adjust the offset up by 2. Conveniently, instead of Column()-2 you can now just use Column() to bring the spreadsheet columns and the lookup offsets into line, so in B8 of the new tab to pull in column D from Master, you enter the formula =vlookup($A8, Master!$C:$S, Column(), 0), then copy the formula across the row for as many columns you need.